# SQL Server stored procedures automatically recompiled?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

If I use a web application Web Data Administrator and I edit the stored procedures SQL query, does it recompile on it's own? (new to SQL Server and this side of the database development)

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL Server does maintain a cache of [query plans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan), but this is not the same as compiled code.

The SQL Server manages this cache and can be the source of some pain if it caches a plan that is non-optimal. Though this has happened to me less than 5 times in 15 years (and that seemed to be a problem with a particular server), ***its best to let SQL server handle this and not touch it***.

You can force SQLServer to recompile by supplying the [WITH RECOMPILE](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-sql-servers-with-recompile-option/5662581) option. Same caveat applies, ***unless you have a substantial reason to, DONT***.

Comment: Yup; but I just find sometimes people have a disconnect when presented with `WITH RECOMPILE`, thinking that it's required in the definition of the Sproc to cause it to clear that sproc from the cache at all. I didn't word what I said right, and it *does* seem to suggest you didn't say what you said, though. Deleting!

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a scripting language, which means the code you write is not compiled.  Rather, it is stored on the server to be used later.

When you edit a stored procedure, you can execute an ALTER script, or a DROP then CREATE script.  This sends the text in your Web Data Admin (or SSMS) window to the server, issuing a command that tells the server to store this new query as a procedure for later use.

So, in short, yes, if you execute an ALTER script.

Comment: Actually, SQL Server stored procedures are 'compiled' upon their first run. [SQL SERVER – Stored Procedure are Compiled on First Run](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/08/sql-server-stored-procedure-are-compiled-on-first-run-sp-taking-longer-to-run-first-time/) This is one of the (marginal) benefits of using Sprocs. Reused text queries get many of the same benefits anymore, though. However, you are correct to note that using `ALTER` (or `DROP` then `CREATE`) does cause a recompile. Otherwise, the new sproc would not take effect.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Excellent point.  I wasn't even thinking about all the SP recompiles and tuning jazz.  Wondering if the original question was about compilation or not...